# TinyMCE-dialogs of Plone site are not translated

Tags: tinymce, translation, plone

The main issue is a dialog for links: for external links the target dialog is empty.
But the issue itself seems to be that this dialog and also other dialogs of TinyMCE and the control panel for TinyMCE is in english, not the language of the website, which is not english.

Any hint where to start debugging?

Plone 4.3.11 , TinyMCE 1.3.23 default for Plone 4.3.11

german

Comment: plone version? tinymce version?

Comment: ...and the language is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the translation-files aren't compiled and that you ran into https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/issues/149, where M. v. Rees makes several suggestions for resolving.

If you have monolingual site, you can also quickly compile the German files manually, like:

```
$ cd eggs/Products.TinyMCE-1.3.23-py2.7.egg/Products/TinyMCE/locales/de/LC_MESSAGES
$ msgfmt -o tinymce.po tinymce.mo
$ msgfmt -o plone.tinymce.po plone.tinymce.mo
```

Comment: Thanks Ida. The configuration of buildout should cause the mo-files to be compiled on start up, but permissions on directories were not enough. After fixing permissions and restarting Zope, the po-Files are compiled to mo-files and the dialogs are filled with text. Unfortunatly they were not even filled with english text before fixing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed feedback, Katja. Yes the default-strings (usually in English) should be shown in any case, that could be a another bug.Did the permission-prob derive of installing Plone as root, respectively how did you fix it?