# Language of Events in Plone Theme

Tags: internationalization, plone, dexterity, plone-5.x

I created a Plonetheme with bobtemplates. Now I have a problem with the language of the events. I want them to be in German (like the rest of the site). But there are only some parts in German; the rest is still in English. How can that be and what can I do to translate everything?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the add-event-page

Comment: Thank you. I can reproduce this, looks like a bug of the new content-types, respectively that translations for them are still missing. Should be unrelated to your theme or bobtemplates

Comment: The translations exists but doesn't seem to be compiled, my `plone.app.event`-egg doesn't contain MO-files. This answer should help you further: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036157/tinymce-dialogs-of-plone-site-are-not-translated/41098320#41098320, replace "Products/TinyMCE" If not, ping back.

Comment: (In general, please ask Plone support questions in our forum, community.plone.org where they are likelier to be seen by more people)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the [instance]-part of the buildout-config and run buildout:

```
environment-vars =
    zope_i18n_compile_mo_files true
```